# Using Project + valueMap in combination with where

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3, graph-traversal, gremlinpython

I have the following graph: https://gremlify.com/vxkibjtoz3b
if u can't open the link the graph is lloking the following:
[image: Graph]

You can see there 2 queries. The first one:
`g.V().out("r").as("a").V().out("rl_pre").out("rl").as("b").where("a", eq("b")).by("attr").select("a", "b")`

gives me all vertices which share the same "attr" value. In the second query:
`g.V().out("r").as("a").V().hasLabel("start").project("lower_pre", "lower"). by(__.out("rl_pre").valueMap("lower_pre_prop")) by(__.out("rl_pre").out("rl").as("b").where("a", eq("b")).by("attr").valueMap("attr"))`

I tried to combine the first query with "project" and "valueMap" to get some values of former attributes. Unfortunately the second query isn't working. Does anyone of know who to get properties of former Vertices + the properties in the graph traversal end vertex in combination with the "where" clause?

**Expected output**

I expect to get all vertex pairs ("upper and lower) which share the same property value for ("attr") + I want to have the "start_attribute" value from the start vertex

Kind regards Stefan

Comment: The first query is going to potentially fan out unexpectedly and be expensive as `V` (all vertices) will be applied to the results of `g.V().out('r')`.  You may want to `fold` first to flatten all of the traversals. Can you sat a bit more about the exact output you are looking to produce?

Comment: Thx for your reply... I edit my article and added the section: Expected output. Hope thie helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the Gremlify data and pretty printing it a little gives us:

```java
g.addV('wrong_node').as('1').property(single, 'attr', 0).
  addV('start').as('2').
  addV('upper').as('3').property(single, 'attr', 1).
  addV('lower').as('4').property(single, 'attr', 1).
  addV('lower_pre').as('5').property(single, 'lower_pre_prop', 666).
  addV('lower_wrong').as('6').property(single, 'attr', 2).
  addV('upper_2').as('7').property(single, 'attr', 1).
  addE('r').from('2').to('7').
  addE('r').from('2').to('3').
  addE('r').from('2').to('1').
  addE('rl_pre').from('2').to('5').
  addE('rl').from('5').to('4').
  addE('rl').from('5').to('6')
```

Using that sample graph, the query can be reduced to:

```java
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('start').as('s').
......1>   out('r').as('a').
......2>   V().hasLabel('start').
......3>   out('rl_pre').
......4>   out('rl').
......5>   where(eq('a')).
......6>     by('attr').as('b').
......7>   select('s','a','b').
......8>     by().
......9>     by(valueMap(true,'attr')).
.....10>     by(valueMap(true,'attr'))
```

which produces (I did not see a "start_attribute" property so left that part out)

```
==>[s:v[2],a:[id:11,label:upper_2,attr:[1]],b:[id:5,label:lower,attr:[1]]]
==>[s:v[2],a:[id:3,label:upper,attr:[1]],b:[id:5,label:lower,attr:[1]]]
```

The `valueMap` step can be replaced by `elementMap` in this case which gives a slightly simpler query and more readable output.

```java
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('start').as('s').
......1>   out('r').as('a').
......2>   V().hasLabel('start').
......3>   out('rl_pre').
......4>   out('rl').
......5>   where(eq('a')).
......6>     by('attr').as('b').
......7>   select('s','a','b').
......8>     by().
......9>     by(elementMap('attr')).
.....10>     by(elementMap('attr'))  

==>[s:v[2],a:[id:11,label:upper_2,attr:1],b:[id:5,label:lower,attr:1]]
==>[s:v[2],a:[id:3,label:upper,attr:1],b:[id:5,label:lower,attr:1]]
```

Comment: Super cool and detailed answer. Thank you very much :) 
Did u like the idea of sharing the graph via gremlify?

Comment: Gremlify is helpful yes, but I also like to have the graph creation steps in the post itself in case one day the graph in Gremlify is deleted etc.